# Spark JDBC queries appear to be duplicating at source

Tags: sql, apache-spark, jdbc, databricks

I am seeing some odd behavior that I can't seem to explain or find an answer for online.  We are switching over a few of our ETL pipelines to custom Workbooks via Databricks (Scala).  Part of my pipeline code does something like this:

```
var upperBoundValue : String = null
if(partitionColumnPresent){
     val upperBoundQuery = s"(select max(${partitionColumn}) as upper from JDBC_URL)results"
     val upperBoundDF = spark.read.jdbc(url=connectionURL, table=upperBoundQuery, 
         properties=connectionPropertiesBounds)
     upperBoundValue = upperBoundDF.first()(0).toString
}
```

Essentially if a "partitionColumn" is present from the incoming metadata about a potential table we plan to ingest, we try and make things a bit more parallel by using upperBound, lowerBound and partitionColumns in the connection properties.  I fetch the upper and lower bounds from the source table first, as depicted in the above snippet.  What I am seeing is that the "max" and "min" queries are executed on each of my nodes in the cluster.  It seems like its only worker nodes though.  I tested with a 3 node cluster and watched my query monitor on the source (Postgres) database system.  When the job kicks off, it executes both the "upper" and "lower" SQL queries two times, which come in over two different PID's.

My initial thought was "there must be a way to run this on the coordinator and pass the value to the executors, right?". But I am not sure. I did try a "broadcast", but I don't think that is what I am looking for here.

FWIW - I don't see this behavior when spark is actually ingesting the data partitions, which get generated from using these bounds, which is also using the same spark.read.jdbc method... which doesn't seem to add up to me.

I am sure I am messing something up. Anyone know what it is?

Comment: To run a query from the coordinator node, use JDBC directly from Scala instead of using spark.read.

Comment: Good idea - thanks David.

Comment: Interestingly, changing it over to using the plain old DriverManager with an execute statement produced 4 identical queries for both min and max, on a three node cluster. Each node has 4 cores, so I suppose that makes sense. I will try and get it down to just running one.

Comment: If the code isn't in a UDF, something else is going on.  Scala code in a notebook executes just on the driver.

Comment: Yeah, no udf.  I will investigate a bit.  I did update my last comment mentioning that the coordinator node is 4 core.